# kwargs.get only pulls first letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python, and I find this bit rather confusing.  I have a config file that is read into a kwarg.  with values like:

```
 students||student a|student b|student c
```

I see this populating properly into the kwarg when I debug, however, when I attempt to read the values, it will always only pull the first letter.

```
 for student in kwargs.get('students'):
   --student will come thru as 's'
```

this seems to be something specific to my machine, as this code is running in prod.  I set my libraries the same as the server, but still having the issue.  Anyone know why this might be occurring?

I am running on Python 3.6.5

Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure what a kwarg is (unless you’re saying that the configuration is passed to a function as a set of keyword arguments), but could you show the code that reads it?

Comment: **How** exactly do you read your config file into `kwargs` ?

Comment: If `kwargs.get('students')` returns a string, then you're iterating over the individual characters of the string.

Comment: `print(type(kwargs.get('students'))`... Is it a string?

Comment: @glibdud  It looks like your right, but now i wonder how the heck this is working properly in prod!  Is there a way to have it grab the whole name?

Comment: @Limey `kwargs.get('students')` is the whole name.

Comment: So the lesson in all of this is just because codes in production, doesn't mean it works right!